# How to display list of buttons which user can scroll up and down in C# Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am developing a simulator of order proccessing machine of McDonald's and I've got an issue associated with displaying the list of buttons which user can scroll up and down in order to  find the suitable product.

I have already dragged on the form the ToolStrip where I have added 14 toolstrip buttons. Each of that buttons represent a product category like: Burgers, Fries & Sides, Salads, Drinks etc. So I want to do toolstrip button so that user click it and on the form appears list of buttons.
Like: For instance, user clicks button which represents category "Burgers" and after that displaying a buttons which represent each of product in this category so the user can choose what he want.

My design of the form is following [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpOS2.png)

So the question is: "What component I should add to the form to perform this operation?"

Thanks in advance! :) :) :)

Comment: Put a Panel Control into the form. Then add the buttons to the Panel.  The Panel can contain a scrollbar.

Comment: Can I add images to the button as well?

Comment: You can add any control to a panel just like a form

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is using a Panel with ScrollableControl.
Refer the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3011773/9556219)